# $X$ r.v of a uniform law, find cdf of $Y=\min(X,a)$ $(a \in [0,1])$ prove the law of Y is linear combination of a density and a Dirac measure

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation, solution-verification, dirac-delta

> Problem : Let $X$ be r.v following a uniform law on $[0,1]$, find the
> cdf of $Y=\min(X,a)$ $(a \in [0,1])$ and prove that the law of Y is
> linear combination of of a law with a density and a Dirac measure.

Solution:

> $\forall t < 0, P(Y\leq t) = 0$
>
> $\forall 0\leq t<a ,$ $P(Y \leq t)=P(X \leq t)=t$
>
> $\forall t \geq  a, P(Y\leq t) = 1$
>
> The cumulative distribution function admits a discontinuity point in
> $a$ where it "jumps" from the value $1-a$ to the value 1.
>
> Let $P_Y$ be the law of Y , ($P_Y$ then has a measure of probability
> on R). We want to write $P_Y$ as a linear combination of a measure of
> a density (when the measure represents the integral of a density) and
> of a Dirac.
>
> We notice that $P_Y(]-\infty , t]) = P(Y \leq t)$ by definition, we
> verify that $P(Y\leq t) = aF_U(t) + (1-a)F_V(t)$   with $F(t)=0$ if $t
> \leq 0$,  $\dots (1) $
>
> $F_U(t) = t/a$ if $t \in [0,a]$
>
> et $F_U(t)=1$ if $t \geq a $
>
> while $F_V(t) = 0$ if $t < a$ and $F_V(t)=1$ if $t \geq a$
>
> We see that $F_U$ is the cumulative distribution function of a uniform
> law on $[0,a]$ $\dots (2) $
>
> And $F_V$ is a cumulative distribution function of Dirac measure on
> $a$
>
> We rewrite $ P_Y(]-\infty,t])=aP_U(]-\infty,t]) +
> (1-a)P_V(]-\infty,t])$ $\dots (3) $
>
> Where $P_U$ is the uniform measure on $[0,a]$ and $P_V$ is that of
> Dirac in a. $\dots (4) $
>
> The law of $Y$, $(P_Y)$ is then a linear combination of
> Dirac in $a$ and the uniform law on $[0,a]$ , weighted respectively
> with $(1-a)$ and $a$

Now, by definition of a Dirac measure, it's a measure supported by a singleton of unitary mass $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$, and it is a probability measure.

$\mathbb{1}_A(a) =\delta_a(A)=
\begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if }a \in A \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

In this problem, it asks for law of $Y=min(X,a)$ where $X$ is a r.v and  $a$ is a fixed given real number in $[0,1]$ in the (1) of the solution , **it directly tries  to verify a supposed result without giving it's construction , or at least I can't see how to directly come up with that to then just verify it?**

for me when I tried to solve it, I assumed a fixed number in its interval and I wrote :

$F_Y(t) = P(min(X,a) \leq t)$

$F_Y = P(\{x \leq t\}\cup\{a \leq t\})$

$F_Y = P(\{x \leq t\}) + P(\{a \leq t\}) -P(\{x \leq t\}\cap\{a \leq t\})$

since I couldn't see something useful coming out of this,
I tried another formulation :

$F_Y = P(\{x \leq t\} \cap \{X \leq a\} \cup \{x \geq a\}\cap\{a \leq t\}) $

since a random variable and a constant are independant

$F_Y = at + (1-F(a^{-}))F(\{a \leq t\}) - t $

$F_Y = at + (1-(a^{-})F(\{a \leq t\}) - t $

since the intersection of all the events implies $X=a$ and $X \leq t$ so the probability of that is $t$ hence the $-t$

But then I didn't know what to do with the $F(\{a \leq t\}) $, or use the Dirac measure, what am I not understanding?

**EDIT** : my reformulation is false particularly for the variables less than $a$ , here's a modified one :

$F_Y = P(\{X \leq t\} \cap \{X \leq a\} \cup \{X \leq t\}\cap\{X \geq a\} \cup \{X \geq t\}\cap\{a \leq t\} ) $

Which then gives :

$F_Y = at + t(1-a^{-})+ F(\{a \leq t\})(1 - t) $ - the intersection of the events two by two + the intersection of all events which I am guessing it's not an efficient way to think about it even if it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more enlightening solution.

Let $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. 
$$\begin{aligned}P_Y(A) 
&= P(\min(X,a)\in A)  \\
&= E(1_A(\min(X,a)) \\
&= E(1_A(\min(X,a)1_{X\leq a}) + E(1_A(\min(X,a)1_{X> a})\\
&= E(1_A(X)1_{X\leq a}) + E(1_A(a)1_{X>a}) \\
&= E(1_{A\cap[0,a] }(X)) + P(X>a)\delta_a(A) \\
&= P_X(A\cap[0,a])+ P(X>a)\delta_a(A)\end{aligned}$$

Since $P_X(A)=0\implies P_X(A\cap[0,a])=0$, the measure $A\mapsto P_X(A\cap[0,a])$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $P_X$, hence absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure (in other words it has a density).

$A\mapsto\delta_a(A)$ is a Dirac measure with mass $1$.

Comment: Thank you, would you please explain the reasoning of going from the first line to the second line, particularly the second term of the second line, of what I understood, using $P(A) = E(1_{A})$ , this line is a decomposition of $A$ the event $\{Y \leq t \}$ to the events: $\{X \in A$ and $X \leq a \}$ $\cup$ $\{a \in A$ and $X > a \}$ , if so, how so?

Comment: @Khan I've added intermediate steps

Comment: Thank you, would you please explain your conclusion of absolute continuity w.r.t $P_X$ or refer me to some result or theorem?

Comment: @Khan Lookup Radon Nikodym theorem.